Trouble logging in: "No user found with matching email"
I have two Google accounts, but I am only logged in Stack Exchange in one account. I lost my password, so I had to recover it. I updated my email address before, but it still says, "No user found with matching email". And somehow Google didn't keep my password, which Google does every time. So now if I somehow got logged out, there is no way in anymore.

It's unclear what you're actually doing/trying to do and exactly what response you're getting. It's unclear what you did with respect to "updated my email", etc. You should [edit] your question to clarify. However, it doesn't really matter, because the answer is very likely to be the same as it is for the vast majority of problems relating to login credentials: Use the "Contact"/"Contact Us" link that's at the bottom of every page to contact the company. They can communicate with you privately.
